# Manage cordova plugins with npm + package.json

Tags: npm, cordova-plugins

We have an Angular + Ionic + Cordova project with multiple devs that we'd like to manage cordova plugin dependencies for. We are using [Cordova CLI 5+](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html), and when manually running the install commands (e.g. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`), a new line gets added to the `cordovaPlugins` section of the `package.json` file. Here's what the finished product looks like:

```
"cordovaPlugins": [
  "cordova-plugin-camera",
  "cordova-plugin-console",
  "cordova-plugin-contacts",
  "cordova-plugin-device",
  "cordova-plugin-dialogs",
  "cordova-plugin-file",
  "cordova-plugin-geolocation",
  "cordova-plugin-media",
  "cordova-plugin-media-capture",
  "cordova-plugin-network-information",
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
  "cordova-plugin-vibration",
  "com.ionic.keyboard"
]
```

That's all great, except we can't find any way for dev #2 to npm install those plugins - instead, he has to run the commands individually, which then adds a duplicate line to `package.json`, dirtying the repository. We are sure there must be a command to install these, but can't find it. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: FWIW, for now we are using gulp-cordova to read a modified version of the above config in from package.json. Will post the full solution, if that turns out to be the solution, once the bounty period expires.

Comment: Does it not get installed when you run cordova build ?

Comment: `cordova plugin add cordova-*` adds a line to the `cordovaPlugins` section of the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**What Caused Our Issue**

We had originally used this [Ionic + Cordova + Grunt seed project](https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic) to spawn our initial app. The [project includes](https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic/tree/master/templates/hooks) a number of [Cordova hooks](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_hooks_index.md.html#Hooks%20Guide) that, among other things, add and remove platforms and plugins from the relevant `cordovaPlatforms` and `cordovaPlugins` sections in `package.json` when you run the corresponding command (i.e. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media` adds a line to `cordovaPlugins`).

To better support local testing (trying new versions of a plugin, for example), and to prevent cross-dev dependency issues, we disabled the seed project hook and now hand-craft the `package.json` as needed.

**Properly Managing Cordova Plugins**

In turns out, the [Ionic CLI](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/) uses `package.json` to manage Cordova app state in terms of platforms and plugins (as of [version 1.3.19](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/commit/4c200b8077bee558dbc7952335c3cbccbc726845#diff-7eb5bb4017472e77b5d93444a1d27154), it appears).

Populating `package.json` with two sections, `cordovaPlatforms` and `cordovaPlugins` has allowed us to do a simple `ionic state restore` to get the Cordova environment in shape for emulation, building, etc.

**Specifying Versions**

To further lock-down our app's state and development environment, we've also specified the target version of the Cordova platforms and plugins that we are using by adding the version number. Here's what we use:

```
{
  ...
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "android@4.0.2",
    "ios@3.8.0"
  ],
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-camera@1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-contacts@1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device@1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file@2.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-media@1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-media-capture@1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information@1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen@2.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar@1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-vibration@1.2.0",
    "com.ionic.keyboard@1.0.5"
  ]
}
```

**tl;dr**

Once you have the above in your `package.json`, you can then ensure that your local environment is in the proper state via `ionic state restore` (v1.3.19+) which will chew through `package.json` and install platforms and plugins as needed.

Comment: Did you find a way to install the plugins from this 'state' that ionic is saving? If so I'd love to see it.

Comment: It might make sense to add "ionic state restore" to the answer above, since that's the actual answer to the question.

Comment: If you see "state is not a valid task" it's because you have an outdated version of ionic-cli. The state command became available in version 1.3.9. To fix, just update ionic like so `npm update -g ionic-cli` and then `ionic state restore` will work.

Comment: Does this install the same version o just pulls the latest version of the plugin? I find it odd that not a single version number appears in the json

Comment: @SDude I've added in versioning info to the answer.

Comment: @jaker if you install plugins with `cordova add plugin ...` you can still add them to `package.json` using `ionic state save` - see also https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli and https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/36573.page

Comment: also, if you're using newer versions of libraries, you may need to `cordova rm plugin ...` old plugin(s) when installing new ones - I ran into duplicates

Comment: @PaulMennega ionic state has been removed as of CLI 3.0. what to do in that case?

Answer (score 13):

You can add a postinstall command. Look below

```
{
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "com.ionic.keyboard@1.0.4",
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "android@4.1.1",
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ionic state restore",
    "clean": "ionic platform remove android; ionic platform remove ios; ionic platform remove browser; git checkout package.json"
  }
}
```

Bonus : use `npm run clean` followed by `npm install` if you wish to start clean i.e reinstall all platforms

Answer (score 1):

may be it's a bit late into the game, but this is my postinstall script

```
    "postinstall": "bower i && gulp && ionic state reset && ionic config build"
```

- it installs the bower dependencies, e.g. ionic lib
- it restores Cordova plugins
- it re-builds the configuration you did via ionic config command