# Difference between ionic and cordova plugin install

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

When working with ionic, what is the difference between

```
ionic plugin install ...
```

and

```
cordova plugin install
```

Which one should be used? And why?

Thx!

Comment: They are the same I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is a difference**

Ionic create some files in the project, such as `ionic.project` and `package.json`.

Each time you add a plugin with Ionic using the command `ionic plugin add ...` , Ionic updates `package.json`.

[Ionic CLI](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/) uses `package.json` to manage Cordova app state in terms of platforms and plugins.

`package.json` has two sections, cordovaPlatforms and cordovaPlugins that allows a `ionic state restore` to get the Cordova environment ready for build, run, etc...

More explanations here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30192417/3096087

Answer (score 0):

**In substance**, there are **no differences** between both commands, they result in the same actions performed on your Ionic project, as clearly stated in [Ionic-cli main page](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli?#cordova-commands), from which here's an extract:

> ### Cordova Commands
>
> Ionic uses Cordova underneath, so you can also substitute Cordova commands to prepare/build/emulate/run, or to add additional plugins.

Nonetheless, there are some **cosmetics** difference. For example the `ionic plugin install` version:

- has colored output while the `cordova` one doesn't
- sends anonymous usage statistics to the ionic server. [[1](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli?#cordova-commands)]

Comment: From the link you sent me, they "occasionally send anonymous usage statistics". Also I see the output is colored different and ionic adds the plugins to package.json. So there is a difference :)

Comment: Nowadays also cordova adds plugins to package.json

Answer (score 0):

cordova is tool which is enabling you to develop hybrid apps using HTML5 and javascript and on the other hand IONIC is a framework on top of Cordova which is providing better html elements(for mobile ) like buttons, lists etc with less efforts go threw [this link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#header).

Answer (score 0):

There are no difference between because IONIC is a framework developed on top of Cordova and wrap it.